# iOS updated on users phone - now app crashes up on opening - can't find sqlite file

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I had an app that I developed a couple years ago - once the users updated to the latest iOS version it began crashing (iOS10).

I have since recreated the app in a web-based version as a PWA and wanted to pull the SQLite file off their phone and import their information into the web app.

Now in xcode when I go to 'Window->Devices' I see their device.

And then click on the installed apps - it doesn't allow me to download the container. If I double click it and open the container - it shows as empty (but there should be an sqlite file there).

I installed iExplorer and went to the app as well - only to find it empty as well.

Is there somewhere else in the system that the sqlite file would be? Or did this iOS update hose the app to the point I should tell users "well, your data is gone - just restart life on the web app"?

Comment: Where was the file stored exactly?

Comment: Is the build of the app on the device a development build?  I don't believe you can access the containers with distribution builds.

Comment: It is a distribution build. Looks like I am hosed?

The file was stored in the apps installation location.

Comment: Unless you can push an update out to the device to push that data to your web service.  Or jailbreak the devices?

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately jailbreaking isn't an option - seems we're hosed. Too bad, but the app is a few years old and hasn't been touched much since it's creation so it was only a matter of time.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access your app container, one of the left option is to backup the iPhone through iTunes, and explore the backup with an application like iExplorer or iBackupBot.